# New line characters not getting reflected properly

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-restapi

I am extracting the subject, sender and the body of a mail and sharing these to another application using outlook add-in. The payload looks like this:

```
var payload = 'Subject: ' + '\n'  + subject + '\n' +
            'Sender: ' + '\n'  + sender + '\n' +
            'Body: ' + '\n' + bodyContent + '\n' +
            'Additional Message: ' + '\n' + addMsg;
```

but the new line characters are not getting reflected properly. It is all in the same line.

Comment: Try using `<br />` instead of `\n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

```
var payload = `Subject:\n${subject}\n\nSender:\n${sender}\n\nBody:\n${bodyContent}\n\nAdditional Message:\n${addMsg}`;
```